# Using to PLYR to count with Which Condition

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use the which function in conjunction with the count function. I would like to count the number of factors that follow a which condition. This code isn't correct, but any advice would be appreciated.

```
library(plyr)
count(data, 'factor', which numeric > 10)

#Base version attempt
count(data$factor, which(data$numeric > 10))

Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for but here are two pieces of advice:

1. `plyr` is an older version of `dplyr` so I would use the newer one, especially because it come in the tidyverse group. `dplyr's` count can deal with factors.
2. Factors aren't commonly used in R anymore. I would suggest just coercing  with `as.character`

With dplyr you could write something like:

```
data %>% filter(numeric > 10) %>% count(factor)
```

Comment: I disagree with your 2nd piece of advice. Factors are very relevant. Here is one example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-novel-method-for-modelling-interaction-between-categorical-variables/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RBloggers+%28R+bloggers%29

Comment: Yeah, there certainly are some places where factors work out better like if you want to put a natural order on a variable. In practice, I think most people just default to characters and Mr. Wickham seems to agree : ["Unfortunately, most data loading functions in R automatically convert character vectors to factors. This is suboptimal, because there’s no way for those functions to know the set of all possible levels or their optimal order. Instead, use the argument stringsAsFactors = FALSE "](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#vectors)